# TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. Trying to build a GUI for my BMI calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("BMI Calculator")

window_width = 300
window_height = 200

# get the screen dimension
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# find the center point
center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

# set the position of the window to the center of the screen
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

root.iconbitmap('./tkinter.ico')

message = tk.Label(root, text="BMI Calculator")
message.pack()

height = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your height in metres.")
height.pack()

textbox = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable="height")
textbox.pack()

weight = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your weight in kilograms.")
weight.pack()

textbox1 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable="weight")
textbox1.pack()

def callback():
    height = float(textbox.get())
    weight = float(textbox1.get())
    bmi = (weight / (height * height))
    printed_bmi = ttk.Label(root, bmi)
    printed_bmi.pack()

button = ttk.Button(root, text="Calculate my BMI!", command=callback).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The error is this:

[image]

How do I fix this? I really just don't understand what this means. I am very new to Python - if somebody could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Change `ttk.Label(root, bmi)` to `ttk.Label(root, text=bmi)`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention the `text=` parameter

This should work

```
printed_bmi = ttk.Label(root, text=bmi)
```

From the source code of [`ttk`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/ttk.py)

You can see that the `__init__` function takes only one `master` parameter other than `self`

```
def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described within the error message. You are sending 3 variables to the function, which takes 2 ...

```
printed_bmi = ttk.Label(root, bmi)
```

The first one is, of course, *self* than root, which is ok but what is bmi? Do you probably mean text = bmi?

So I would suggest changing the line to

```
printed_bmi = ttk.Label(root, text=bmi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `text=bmi` parameter just like how other answers say.

And also, it is better to make a button outside the function or else, more than 1 labels can be created. Then you can change the label inside the function -

```
printed_bmi = ttk.Label(root,text='')

def callback():
    height = float(textbox.get())
    weight = float(textbox1.get())
    bmi = (weight / (height * height))
    printed_bmi.config(text=bmi)
    printed_bmi.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's much cleaner than what I had previously.